# How to read UDP broadcast datagrams in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp, datagram

I was Googling a lot, even on Stackoverflow without find any solution to my problem. I am able to create a server which can listen on a given port.

```
require 'socket'
listenPort = 1001
ss = UDPSocket.new()
ss.bind('', listenPort) #listen all IPs 
while true do
  p ss.recvfrom(2000)
end
ss.close
```

I am able to create a client that send messages on an over computer, on the same Vlan :

```
require 'socket'
listenPort = 1001
sc = UDPSocket.new
cpt = 0
5.times do
  cpt += 1
  sc.send("Hello #{cpt}", 0, "100.64.212.151", listenPort)
end
sc.close
```

All work fine even using the 1001 port which need sudo to perform well on linux. But I need to read/receive packets from a programm (which use 1001 port) on an over computer.

I know my server listen :

```
$ netstat -n --udp --listen | grep 1001
> udp    0   0 0.0.0.0:1001     0.0.0.0:*
```

Using Wireshark, I know that messages arrives on the computer where the server is listen :

```
> N° Time   Source          Destination  protocol Length Info  
> 1  0.OOO  100.64.212.150  225.1.1.1    UDP      639    54672->1001 Len 597
> Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 100.64.212.150, Dst: 225.1.1.1
> User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 54672, Dst Port: 1001
> Data (597 bytes)
```

But my simple server never see anything unless the messages I send with my own client. I don't know how to perform with Ruby (or an over language Java, PHP..) what Wireshark is able to do. I understant that Wireshark run at very low level, but I don't understant what I should do more to make my server listen the packets I am looking for.

Comment: can you try `ss.bind('0.0.0.0', listenPort)` please

Comment: I already did it. It is the same as ss.bind('', listenPort) like netstat said us.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake. It was not a problem with broadcast but a problem dealing with multicast.

For multicast you have to register your server to listen. I found the explanation at [github.com/jpignata/blog/blob/master/articles/multicast-in-ruby.md](https://github.com/jpignata/blog/blob/master/articles/multicast-in-ruby.md). So there is two lines to add before the bind :

```
membership = IPAddr.new(MULTICAST_ADDR).hton + IPAddr.new(BIND_ADDR).hton
s.setsockopt(:IPPROTO_IP, :IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, membership)
```

For that you have to :

```
require 'ipaddr'
```

and define the MULTICAST_ADDR='225.1.1.1' and BIND_ADDR='0.0.0.0' (or ='')

The server become :

```
require 'socket'
require 'ipaddr'

listenPort = 1001
MULTICAST_ADDR = '225.1.1.1'
BIND_ADDR = '0.0.0.0'

s = UDPSocket.new
membership = IPAddr.new(MULTICAST_ADDR).hton + IPAddr.new(BIND_ADDR).hton
s.setsockopt(:IPPROTO_IP, :IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, membership)
s.bind BIND_ADDR, listenPort
while true do
  p ss.recvfrom(2000)
end
s.close
```